# Use ffmpeg to generate videos from images with accurate duration of two decimal numbers

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to generate a video from an image with a given duration. The duration can have milliseconds up to three decimal numbers.

Let's generate a simple image for our experimentation. The following command generates a 100x100 image where all the pixels are red.

```sh
convert -size 100x100 xc:red red.png
```

I know that it is possible to generate a video from an image by passing the following flags to `ffmpeg`. We can also use `ffprobe` to print the duration of the file.

```sh
ffmpeg -v error -y -loop 1 -i red.png -t 3 output.mp4
ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=duration -print_format default=nk=1:nw=1 output.mp4
```

```
3.000000
```

When I set the duration to `3.1`, `ffprobe` shows `3.12` as the duration of the file. However, I want the duration of the resulting file to be `3.1`.

```sh
ffmpeg -v error -y -loop 1 -i red.png -t 3.1 output.mp4
ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=duration -print_format default=nk=1:nw=1 output.mp4
```

```
3.120000
```

How to make `ffmpeg` create a video file with a duration of `3.1` seconds?

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg defaults to 25fps (if frame rate is not stated).

25fps = 40ms per frame. 3.12secs divides by 40ms. 3.1secs does not.

You need to use the `-r` flag to set the frame rate to 50fps (20ms per frame), or any value that 3.1 is divisible by.

To set a precise duration with ffmpeg, the duration must always be a multiple of the frame duration, or ffmpeg will round off to the nearest PTS.